# sshing in aws load balancer and configuring it for subdomain routing?

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, subdomain, load-balancing, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We want to use Amazon Elastic BeanStalk service for deployment in EC2 Boxes.
We want to deploy our Ruby on Rails Application in such a way that we can do sub-domain based routing to different rails app.

And we want to use single SSL Certificate for our load balancer and want to configure our load balancer in susch a away tha subdomain based routing takes place.
HA Proxy does this work well but when we are trying to use Amazon Elastic BeanStalk service for our deployment, aws creates a load balancer but didn't associate it with any Key-Pair.
So we are not able to ssh in load balancer and add our configuration for subdomain based routing.

Can someone please point me to some solution ?

Thanks,
Ankit.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html

Answer (score 2):

You don't SSH into AWS load balancers, they are basically a black box that you have only a limited set of configuration options for.  You probably need to look at the [Route 53](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/) services for DNS routing.

Your configuration would have routing based on domain DNS to different load balancers, one for each separate service you need. You can't have a single ELB route traffic to different EC2 instances based on domain or URI fragments.